# Передача массива изображений по сети

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.
Неожиданно столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно передавать изображения по очереди по сети. Изображения генерируются и сохраняются на компьютере. Далее из нужно передать по сети. На приемник поступает только 1 файл, который растет до бесконечности, вместо того чтобы принимать каждую картинку в отдельности. Не подскажите, где ошибка.

Передача:

```
while(true){           
    BufferedOutputStream(soketOutStream);

    File file = new File (index + ".jpg");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int readed;
    while ((readed = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
        baos.write(buf, 0, readed);
    }
    fis.close();

    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();    
    bisOutVideo.write(data, 0, data.length);
    bisOutVideo.flush();
    bisOutVideo.close();
}
```

Приемник:

```
int counti=0;

bisIn = new BufferedInputStream(soketInputStream)
while (true) {
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(messagerInput+"/"+counti+".jpg");
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    while ((count = bisIn.read(b)) != -1) {
        file.write(b, 0, count);
    }
    file.close();
    counti++;
}
```

Из цикла не выходит, длиться до бесконечности - `while ((count = bisIn.read(b)) != -1)`

Comment: А вы уверены, что именно на этот цикле зависает? У вас что на передаче, что на приёме установлены `while (true)`, в которых нет ни одного `break`-a. Это же самые настоящие бесконечные циклы.

Comment: В том то и дело, что цикл while(true) не работает, в него заходит один раз и виснет на цикле while ((count = bisIn.read(b)) != -1), я так понимаю не передается символ конца файла -1, где-то ошибка

Comment: В вопрос стоит добавить воспроизводимый пример. На данный момент у вас в нём, например, есть загадочные (не объявленные явно в представленном коде) переменные `soketOutStream`, `soketInStream`, `bisOutVideo`. Это нужно, чтобы можно было протестировать и найти проблему в коде. Пока что могу сказать, что постоянные запись и чтение без `sleep`-ов в бесконечном цикле не являются здравой конструкцией и могут угробить что угодно.

Comment: Сейчас подготовлю эту часть кода и постараюсь добавить

Answer (score 0):

На сегодняшний момент решил проблему таким образом. В переменную count поступает количество считанных байт. В данном случае оно равно 1024, если считался полный объем. Если значение меньше 1024, то это признак конца файла и файл можно закрывать. В моем случае этого условия достаточно. Очень странно, что при передачи данных нет метода конца файла.